# Very slow connection to distant oracle DB using OCI and instant client

Tags: php, oracle, query-optimization, oracle-call-interface, instantclient

I have a Zend 1.1 Application, which became very slow when migrated to the production local network. The application is hosted on a Virtual Server and through OCI and Instant Client connects to a distant Oracle schema on the same network.

To avoid any application specific reasons behind this latency, I have created a small script that connects and grab data from a DB table, as following:

```
<?php
$username = "Username";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =     localhost)(PORT = 1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SID = xe) ) )";

$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $dbname);

$query = 'select * from SCS_SYS_ROLES';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$r = oci_execute($stid);

// Fetch each row in an associative array
print '<table border="1">';
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) {
   print '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $item) {
    print '<td>'.($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : '&nbsp').'</td>';
  }
  print '</tr>';
 }
print '</table>';
// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);

// Measuring time...
$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
echo "<p>".$time."</p>";


?>
```

Two copies of this script, with different configuration prove around 40 times difference in speed.  When the script is connected to a local instance of Oracle express it takes around 0.1 second, while when it runs on the distant DB it takes more than 4.3 seconds.

If any one have an explanation or a way to fix this problem I will be thankful. What are the other options for Drivers to use instead of OCi, This would worth to be tested.

Comment: Well, network latency? Slow Intranet?

Comment: The intranet I am dealing with is stable and no one of the hundreds of developers who use it complain about latency!

Comment: There are too many possibilities here to answer accurately. Have you stepped through the code with a debugger and isolated where the slowness happens? (At the very least `echo` out the runtime before/after each `oci_*` function call.)

Comment: Yes, I did, Any query (Even Simple ones) takes around three seconds on calling the fetchAll() Zend function which calls the oci_*.